# Using CSS to selectively display content, avoiding conflicts

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

I'm using CSS to selectively display content depending on viewport size. E.g.:

CSS:

```
.hires, .midres, .lowres {
  display: none;
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 801px) {     /* hires, desktop */
  .hires {
    display: inline;
  }
}

@media only screen
            and (min-width: 600px)
            and (max-width: 800px) {            /* mid res, tablet */
  .midres {
    display: inline;
  }
}

@media only screen
            and (min-width: 320px)
            and (max-width: 599px) {            /* Low res / smartphone */
  .lowres {
    display: inline;
  }
}
```

HTML:

```
<p class="hires">Resolution: high.</p>
<p class="midres">Resolution: medium.</p>
<p class="lowres">Resolution: low.</p>
<p>This paragraph will always be displayed regardless of resolution.</p>
```

Which works, but only up to a point. When it comes to images, it turns out that I've neatly painted myself into a corner here. Because somewhere down the line there's something like:

CSS:

```
@media only screen
            and (min-width: 320px)
            and (max-width: 599px) {           /* Low res / smartphone */
  img {
    float: none;
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
  }
}
```

Which means that in the following case:

```
<img src="foo.jpg" class="hires" />
```

the image is always displayed regardless of viewport size, because the 'display: block;' overrides (conflicts with, really) the preceding rules to selectively display the image or not.

Unfortunately 'display' has no opposite of 'none'. I can't use 'visibility' because that will still leave a gap where the hidden content used to be. I could use jQuery to show() and hide() content, but I'd rather not move part of my styling from the style sheets (where it belongs) to Javascript (where, strictly speaking, it doesn't).

Unfortunately I noticed this little snafu only now,  quite a way into the project. Which means I'm an idiot. :-)

What would be the best way to deal with the above issue?

Comment: Apologies if I have misunderstood but are you saying that `img{display: block;}` is over ruling `.hires{display: none;}`? This shouldn't be the case because `.hires` is more specific than `img` so something else may be in play here. Would you be able to supply a reproducible example of the exact issue you are facing?

Comment: Are you saying that `display:none` doesn't work on images?

Comment: What exactly is the problem here? http://jsfiddle.net/hjq0hthc/

Comment: First (overall) CSS rule:  `code` .hires,.midres,.lowres{display: none;} hides all content to be displayed selectively (leaving other content alone). Subsequent rules selectively apply `code` display:inline to these elements. However a subsequent overall `code` 'display:block' is applied to all images regardless of whether they are supposed to be displayed or not, and as soon as that happens the image is displayed because the display property is no longer 'none'.

Answer (score 1):

You could either wrap images in something with the class lores or use `img.lowres` as selector in your css, ie

```
@media only screen
            and (min-width: 320px)
            and (max-width: 599px) {           /* Low res / smartphone */
  img.lowres {
    float: none;
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
  }
}
```

Comment: Reading this, I realized that I omitted to include in the example some content that should always be displayed regardless of viewport size. Meaning that the above will work for my initial example but not the corrected one. My bad.

Comment: @FrankvanWensveen it will still work for the corrected example. img.lowres is more specific than img